# Update OwnerId of ContentDocument from Apex class

Tags: apex, contentversion, contentdocument

I need to update OwnerId of ContentDocument in my Apex class.For thati am updating it like this:

```
if(!participantDocumentsOwnerId.isEmpty() && participantDocumentsOwnerId.size() > 0 && !users.isEmpty() && users.size() > 0) {
    for(ContentDocumentLink participantDocs : participantDocumentsOwnerId) {
        ContentVersion version = new ContentVersion();
        version.id = participantDocs.ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId;
        version.OwnerId = users[0].Id; 
        documentOwnerToBeUpdated.add(version);
        system.debug('participantDocs.ContentDocument.OwnerId '+participantDocs.ContentDocument.OwnerId);
    }
                        
}

update documentOwnerToBeUpdated;
```

I am using ContentVersion to update ContentDocument data as described
[here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/98183/contentdocument-object)

But i am getting Cross reference entity error. I am updating the record through some other profile than System admin, so if its permission issue where can i check contentVersion permissions.

> Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a2y110000012zi0AAA;
> first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, ParticipantTrigger:
> execution of AfterUpdate
>
> caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row
> 1 with id 06811000001yHzlAAE; first error:
> INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, You do not have
> permission to change the owner of this document: []

Comment: for that given document, [who is it shared](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_files_sharing_people_lex.htm&type=0) with and is the user able to update the owner of a Document they currently own? Do you have file sharing set to [inherit record permissions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.admin_files_on_record_sharing_setting.htm&type=5)?

Comment: system administrator is able to update owner i tried through ananymous window and owner was changed.

Comment: I checked and came to know that class is running with Sharing So the user with this profile needs to have update access to update contentDocument. I actually have Document__c custom object which is linked through ContentDocumentLink obj. Where can i modify or give edit access to that user?

Answer (score 1):

Two things to consider, sharing of files and permissions.

When a file is uploaded to a record, for sharing, the following occurs:

- The owner has the "Owner" share type
- Users who can see the record can see the file

There's a setting called [Set file access to Set by Record for files attached to records.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.admin_files_on_record_sharing_setting.htm&type=5) that will allow users who can edit the record to inherit that setting so that they can edit files (become a collaborator). This only applies to files uploaded *after* the setting is turned on. However, this does not include `Owner` edits.

---

The permissions related to changing ownership is highlighted in the *Special Access Rules* of [ContentDocument](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.220.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm)

> A user can change ownership of a Salesforce CRM Content document or
> Salesforce file if any of the following are true:
>
> - The user is the current owner, or has either the “Modify All Data” or    "Manage Salesforce CRM Content” permission enabled.
> - The user has the “Manage Library” permission enabled for the library    containing the document.

The problem with the above, is that `Modify All Data` is a no-go for giving non-admins and the other option, enabling `Manage Salesforce CRM Content`, gives the following dependent permissions:

- View Setup & Configuration
- Customize Application

In testing, the `Manage Salesforce CRM Content` permission didn't even seem to give the ability to change owner, but `Modify all Data` did.

Either way, the most viable/restrictive way to give access seems to be held within the last point, about library access. Creating a library allows you to give a public group (many users, all users, etc) or specific users `Author` permission for the library. You can have users upload files first to that specific library (through `Files` app) and then add it to the record like so.
[image]

Otherwise, you could automate adding all ContentDocuments to that given library that all users are authors for. This would allow them to change the owner without giving some of the more expansive permissions highlighted above.

The last thing to consider is **why is it important for them to be the Owner**? If you enabled the setting at the top (inherit record access) - users who can edit the record the file is on get collaborator access and can upload new versions. Being an owner might not add that much value to change if the user can still upload a new version and edit the other details.